# Adding an Event on ASP.NET sites

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I am trying to create a button on an ASP.net site which when you press it, enables a music player to start streaming music on the site.

I know how to create the button and how to handle events, I just can't enable my player to start playing the *.mp3 file.

This is the music player that im using on regular html sites.

```
 <embed src="music/ToGlory.mp3" width="140" height="40" autostart="false" loop="TRUE" hidden="True"></embed>
```

What I was trying to do looks like this:

> Sub submit(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
>
> button=embed src="music/ToGlory.mp3" width="140" height="40" autostart="false" loop="TRUE" hidden="True"  /embed
>
> End Sub

Comment: Well it won't matter at this point because the server is crashing and the error log does not really say much

Comment: Logging system is one of the first things you should add to the website. See if there's anything in system's event viewer - applications or system logs.

Comment: That's true I will have to research this more since I'm new to ASP.NET and I am learning it by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

The .aspx `Button` control

```
<asp:button id="Button1"
       usesubmitbehavior="true"
       text="Click it and Play it!"
       onclientclick="Play('URL to sound file, ex: http://www.my.com/a.mp3')"
       runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function Play(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("Button1").innerHTML=
 "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 }
 </script>
```

+1 if this helps :) .

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Is it possible to guide me a bit on the <script> code for the button?

Comment: I will for sure. Let me plug it in and see what happens

Comment: Please notice that in the `getElementById` function you must pass the `Button` id which is defined in the markup.

Comment: What does it mean  BC30456: 'Button1_Click' is not a member of 'ASP.startmusic_aspx'.

Comment: Ok is it working now? I suggest you to pass the id of the `Button`

Comment: Well, as I said I am new to ASP.NET so im not familiar with the errors that I'm getting.Still working on it.

Comment: Do i need Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) around the function?

Comment: Do you plan to do something else? if not then simply remove it... or put it put leave it empty..(not recommended)

Comment: no. the main goal of the site is to say "Hello press this button to listen to the music file" that's all i'm trying to accomplish. I asked because this is a new error that im getting after i passed the correct arguments to the function. This is the error log: Compiler Error Message: BC31143: Method 'Protected WithEvents Button1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.

Comment: Ok remove the `onClick` attribute then

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7269/discussion-between-crematorio-and-rofans-net)